# How to sum array with quantity key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Test1"
    ["weight"]=>
    string(3) "5.0"
    ["price"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Test2"
    ["weight"]=>
    string(3) "7.0"
    ["price"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

I can add up the price with this:

```
echo array_sum(array_column($items, 'price'));
```

But I am having trouble accounting for items that have more than 1 in quantity. How can I sum this up correctly in PHP?

Edit: the issue with my code, incase it is not clear is it does not take into account the items with more than 1 in the quantity. The total for this should be 25. The code I used says it is 18.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand the issue. The code you show works as I would expact so maybe you could explain what it output you get and then whats wrong with it

Comment: It doesn't take into account items with more than 1 in quantity,

Comment: Ohhh, but thats because PHP is not Magical. You didnt code anything to take the quantity into account so it didnt even try

Comment: Yeah, it was the code I was using before I added in quantity in the array, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo array_reduce(
    $items, 
    function($total, $item) {
        $total += $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];

        return $total;
    }, 
    0
);
```

Or a simple `foreach`:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $total += $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: Any benefits with either way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **array_walk** function

```
$total = 0;
array_walk( $arr, function ( $item ) use ( &$total )
{
$total += $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];
});
echo $total;
```